# Managing sound in android through MediaPlayer

Tags: android, audio, media-player, android-mediaplayer

My android application has two buttons. Each of them will play a sound of size 1.5 seconds if clicked. I have used **`MediaPlayer`** to achieve this. The problem is when i click one button and press another within less the 1.5 sec, the second sound wont play . My requirement is when i press the second button I want the first sound to be stopped and the second sound should start playing. How do i achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

When you press the 2nd button and the music is still playing, you need to stop that music and then start playing the 2nd button's song.

so add this to your button

```
   if (mPlayer.isPlaying()) {
        mPlayer.stop();
        mPlayer.reset();
        mPlayer.release();
        mPlayer = null;
    }

   mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, YourMusicHere); 
   mPlayer.start();
```